# Record from microphone in Windows Phone, FFT every 0.1 sec

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, sdk, fft

I need to get data from microphone with 44100hz sampleRate.
And every 0.1sec to do some analysis with fft. 
Here my code:

```
        dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(33);
        dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
        dt.Start();

        // Event handler for getting audio data when the buffer is full
        microphone.BufferReady += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(microphone_BufferReady);

        // Get audio data in 1/10 second chunks
        microphone.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);

        // Allocate memory to hold the audio data
        buffer = new byte[microphone.GetSampleSizeInBytes(microphone.BufferDuration)];

        // Start recording
        microphone.Start();


    void microphone_BufferReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve audio data
        microphone.GetData(buffer);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(buffer.Length + " " +  microphone.SampleRate);

        // ...  fft(buffer) ... some analysis
    }
```

How i can change SampleRate to 44100 and to get buffer with size 4410 (or 4096) every 0.1 sec??? 
Thank

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Microphone class doesn't support sample rate conversion. You cannot change the sample rate on a Windows Phone device. The audio playback and record rate is set by the OEM. Because of this you will need to do the sample rate conversation yourself.

I hope this helps,

James